# Looping over a protobuff enum in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently using protobuff3 on Python 3.7 to serialize packets and transfer them over the network. Before refactoring, I was using a regular enum, but now I've moved on to protobuff enums. However I did not find a way to check if the value is in the enum. In plain python I would do it `if item in enum:`. What would be the best way to do it ?

My protobuff file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package vlcTogether;

message defaultPacket {
    Commands command = 1;
    string param = 2;

    enum Commands {
        ERROR = 0;
        JOIN = 1;
        QUIT = 2;
        VLC_COMMAND = 3;
        SERVER_INFO = 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultPacket` of `google.protobuf.pyext.cpp_message.GeneratedProtocolMessageType` has a `Commands` attribute.

This attribute is an instance of `google.protobuf.internal.enum_type_wrapper.EnumTypeWrapper` and has the following methods `Name` and `Value`.

The `Name` method returns the name for an integer when it exists in the `Enum` or raises a `ValueError`.

The `Value` method returns the value for a string when it exists in the `Enum` or raises a `ValueError` similarly.

```
def valuenum_in_enum(enum_wrapper, valuenum):
    try:
        if enum_wrapper.Name(valuenum):
            return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def valuename_in_enum(enum_wrapper, valuename):
    try:
        if enum_wrapper.Value(valuename):
            return True
    except ValueError:
        return False 

>>> valuenum_in_enum(defaultPacket.Commands, 2)
True
>>> valuename_in_enum(defaultPacket.Commands, 'QUIT')
True
```

Another straight-forward approach is using `DESCRIPTOR` attribute of `Commands`. 
It has `values_by_number` and `values_by_name` properties that return mappings.
For example,

```
>>> commands_descriptor = defaultPacket.Commands.DESCRIPTOR

>>> 'QUIT' in commands_descriptor.values_by_name
>>> 2 in commands_descriptor.values_by_number
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the second one, that's exactly what i need.